# R: storing plots generated in loop in list and passing to multiplot

Tags: r

```
library("ggplot2")
library("Rmisc")

myplots <- list()
x = seq(1,100,1)
y = seq(1,100,1)

for(i in 1:10) {
    myplots[[i]] <- plot(x,y)
}

multiplot(plotlist = myplots, cols=2)
```

I receive the following error:

> Error in unit(rep_len(1, nrow), "null") :    'x' and 'units' must have
>   length > 0 In addition: Warning message: In matrix(seq(1, cols *
>   ceiling(numPlots/cols)), ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols)) :
>   data length exceeds size of matrix

Comment: In the real code, the for loop generates unique and meaningful plots, but I have simplified it here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using ggplot object , you are using R base plot hence multiplot not working:

You should do this:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("Rmisc")

myplots <- list()
x = seq(1,100,1)
y = seq(1,100,1)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

for(i in 1:10) {
  myplots[[i]] <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
}

multiplot(plotlist = myplots, cols=2)
```

**?multiplot:**

```
Usage

  multiplot(..., plotlist = NULL, cols = 1, layout = NULL)
Arguments

...      ggplot objects
plotlist a list of ggplot objects
cols     Number of columns in layout
layout   A matrix specifying the layout. If present, 'cols' is ignored
         Note
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot multiplot only works with ggplots. Wish there were an equivalent genetic multiplot that worked for any plot type...